# Xamarin Frame causes an Java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: xamarin, out-of-memory

I have a loop that adds a grid to a StackLayout for each patient (about 70 records). The grid has a column for a picture (the source of which is a url) and a column for the name. I thought it was the pictures that were causing the out of memory condition, but after hours of stepping through the code, I stumbled on what seems to be the culprit. If I wrap the grids in a frame, that seems to be an issue. I am using Xamarin 4.2.1.62.

I really do want a frame around each patient so I can have a border around each one. Anyone have any ideas?

For a reproducible example, create a page with a single StackLayout

```
<StackLayout  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="StackPatientList"></StackLayout>
```

Then, right after your InitializeComponent() call in the page, call this function:

```
private void InitPatients()
    { 

        ObservableCollection<Patient> PatientsList = new ObservableCollection<Patient>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            PatientsList.Add(new Patient() { FirstName = "First " + i.ToString(), LastName = "Last " + i.ToString() });
        }

        StackLayout oStack = new StackLayout() { };
        this.StackPatientList.Children.Clear();

        foreach (Patient oPat in PatientsList)
        {
            Grid oGrid = new Grid();

            oGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(100, GridUnitType.Auto) });
            oGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });

            oGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(100, GridUnitType.Absolute) });
            oGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

            Image oPatImage = new Image() { Source = oPat.Picture, WidthRequest = 100, HeightRequest = 100 };
            Label oPatLabel = new Label() { Text = oPat.FullName, FontSize = 15, VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center };
            oGrid.Children.Add(oPatLabel, 0, 0);
            oGrid.Children.Add(oPatImage, 1, 0);

            Frame oFrame = new Frame() { OutlineColor = Color.Black, Padding = 5, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand };
            oFrame.Content = oGrid;

            //this.StackPatientList.Children.Add(oGrid);  // Using this works fine
            this.StackPatientList.Children.Add(oFrame);  // This causes an out of memory error
        }

    }
```

Using this as your Patient class:

```
 public class Patient
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get { return LastName + ", " + FirstName; } }
    public string Picture { get; set; }
}
```

Run it on an android device (I use an LG-G3) and you will get an out of memory error.  Then comment out the  line that adds the frame and un-comment the line that just adds the grid and it will work fine.

Comment: where exactly do you call this loop in your code? do you really want to create grid per patient? More code of this page/activity would help. Are you using XForms?

Comment: This is just a method that I am calling after the page appears and the PatientsList is populated.  I do want a grid per patient because I want the image to be on the left and the name to the right on each row.

Comment: I don't want to guess what you have done where and recreate your images and UI page. do you have a sample solution you can share to reproduce? Then I can take a look

Comment: Your question inspired me to break out my code into a very simple example.

Comment: I edited my post with a reproducible example

Comment: Perfect. I am going to try tomorrow. Does this happen in emulator too or just on device?

Comment: Meantime the question. You said: I want the image to be on the left and the name to the right on each row. Why stacklayout doesn't work for you?

Comment: Don't get any exception. Getting frames and images. Try to update nuget packages, clean and rebuild. I would also consider to use ListView

Comment: Does it work for you?